# Hard integral fraction on exponent and fraction multiplying

Tags: integration, exponential-function, contour-integration, fractions

How does one integrate this, just came across this in a project and couldn't do it

$$\int^1_{-1}\frac{a}{x-a}e^{-b/x}dx$$

I was thinking first substitution but it didn't work, then my next idea was a contour but was exactly sure how to approach it.

Comment: I think this will involve the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) and thus not have a closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: It doesn't converge (if $a,b\neq 0$).

Comment: You can expand the integrand in an infinite series about the origin.

Answer (score 0):

For the antiderivative, considering
$$I=\int\frac{a}{x-a}e^{-\frac b x}\,dx$$first, let $x=\frac b t$ and then partial fraction decomposition to make
$$I=\int \frac{a b e^{-t}}{t (a t-b)}\,dt=a\int \frac{e^{-t}}{ t-\frac ba}\,dt-a\int \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt$$ For the first, make now $t=y+\frac ba$to make
$$\int \frac{e^{-t}}{ t-\frac ba}\,dt=e^{-\frac{b}{a}}\int \frac{e^{-y}}{y}\,dy$$ Now
$$\int \frac{e^{-z}}{z}\,dz=\text{Ei}(-z)$$ where appears the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Back to $x$, we then have
$$I=a \left(e^{-\frac{b}{a}}
   \text{Ei}\left(\frac{b}{a}-\frac{b}{x}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{b}{x}\right)
  \right)$$

and then, for the integral

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{a}{x-a}e^{-\frac b x}\,dx=a \left(e^{-\frac{b}{a}} \left(\text{Ei}\left(\left(\frac{1-a}{a}\right)
   b\right)-\text{Ei}\left(\left(\frac{1+a}{a}\right)
   b\right)\right)+\text{Ei}(b)-\text{Ei}(-b)\right)$$

Comment: The integral converges only if $i b \in \mathbb R \land a \not \in [-1, 0) \cup (0, 1]$. Typically $\operatorname {Ei}(z)$ is defined by taking the p.v. integral for $z > 0$ and extending it analytically to $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$. Then $I$ is discontinuous at zero, the integral is $I(1) - I(+0) + I(-0) - I(-1)$. A continuous antiderivative can be given in terms of $E_1(z) = \Gamma(0, z)$ (defined as continuations from $z > 0$ to $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$).